# How to query multiple accepted values with @Query in JPA and JPQL?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, jpql

```
@Query("Select DISTINCT ord from Order ord where ord.status = :status)
public Page<Order> search(String status) ;
```

Is there a way to allow status to match for multiple values?

like 
GET /search?status="done or pending"

Comment: @Query("Select DISTINCT ord from Order ord where ord.status in :statusList")
public Page<Order> search(List<String> statusList) ;

Comment: This almost works, but in my query I have, (ord.status in :statusList or :statusList is null) and the second part breaks. Error. org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: {vector} –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@User9123 has put it correctly,

```
@Query("Select DISTINCT ord from Order ord where (ord.status in :statusList or ord.status is null)") 
public Page<Order> search(List<String> statusList) ;
```

Also to get list of parameter in your controller change request like this.

```
GET /search?status=done,pending
```

and in controller

```
@RequestMapping("/search")
public void search(@RequestParam List<String> statusList) 
{
   // Handle values here
}
```

Comment: This almost works, but in my query I have, (ord.status in :statusList or :statusList is null) and the second part breaks. Error. org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: {vector}

Comment: No you misunderstood, I'm allow null for the input parameter, not the entity. And the problem is when that value is a list, it cant be compared to null

Comment: didnt understand, you mean like this where ord.status in ('done','pending','null')

Comment: No I mean doing a query like this GET /search?status="". Right now that throws exception. Error is this "org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: {vector}:  AND (ord.status in (:statusList_0, :statusList_1) or (:statusList_0, :statusList_1 is null)"

Comment: In case there is no status filter is applied, it would be good if you handle this at client side that way it GET /search will be called and no filter will be applied. In controller statusList would be blank so you can have search override method without status parameter.

Comment: actually I fixed it, with an extra bracket around :statusList. Will accept answer